# Explanation about $B'$ in Frenet formulas?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading some class notes about Frenet's formulas. In the notes, we are deriving $B'$ in terms of $T,N,B$ so it goes like this:

> We write $B'=aT+bN+cB$. Due to lemma $1.1$ (below) we have that $c=B\cdot B'=0$. Now deriving $B\cdot T=0$, we obtain $B'T+BT'=0$ and hence $a=B'\cdot T=-B\cdot T'=-B\cdot \kappa N=0$. With this, we conclude that $B'$ is a scalar multiple of $N$. We write $B'=-\tau N$ and call $\tau(s)$ the torsion of the curve.
>
> **Lemma 1:** If $F$ is a differentiable vector field with constant norm along $\alpha$, then $F$, $F'$ are orthogonal.

**Question:** What is happening here? It's not clear how the deductions are being made, I initially thought that they were multiplying $B'=aT+bN+cB$ by $B'$ on both sides but got lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B'=aT+bN+cB$. If you put $B$ in place of $F$ in lemma 1, you get $B,B'$ are mutually orthogonal. Therefore $0=B\cdot B'=B\cdot(aT+bN+cB)=cB\cdot B$. Hence $c=0$.

Next, since $B\cdot T$ is identically zero, by the product rule in calculus, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
0&=(B\cdot T)'\\
&=B'\cdot T+B\cdot T'\\
&=(aT+bN)\cdot T+B\cdot(\kappa N)\\
&=a+0=a.
\end{aligned}
$$
As both $a$ and $c$ are zero, we have $B'=bN$ for some scalar $b$.

> ...we conclude that $B'$ is a scalar multiple of $\color{red}{B}$.

I think this is a typo. The $B$ in red should read $N$.